# Where can I get FULL mechanical drawings of Pis?

Tags: hardware

Anyone know where I can get the **FULL** mechanical drawings of the Pis?

I have found many drawings - but the cover only the top PCB perspective - i.e. the do not cover left/right/front/back perspectives, and are thus unsuitable to design a 3D case from.

Do these exist anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

There are many existing 3D models of Raspberry Pis available for free at [grabcad.com](https://grabcad.com/library?page=1&time=all_time&sort=popular&query=raspberry%20pi). Your question implies that you already have access to some modelling software, so it should be fairly trivial to pull the necessary dimensions from these models. The following is a quickly-grabbed selection that look about right - when using GrabCad models it's always a good idea to, at a minimum, check the comments regarding the model's accuracy. I've come across one or two that are *nearly*, but not exactly right.

[Pi A](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-a)

[Pi B](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-b-1)

[Pi A+](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-model-a-1)

[Pi B+](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-model-b-2)

[Pi 2](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-3d-cad-assembly-model-2)

[Pi Compute Module](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-compute-module-1)

[Pi Zero](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-zero-2)

[Pi Camera](https://grabcad.com/library/raspberry-pi-camera-3)